# efficiently checking that string consists of one character in Python

Tags: python, string

What is an efficient way to check that a string `s` in Python consists of just one character, say `'A'`? Something like `all_equal(s, 'A')` which would behave like this:

```
all_equal("AAAAA", "A") = True

all_equal("AAAAAAAAAAA", "A") = True

all_equal("AAAAAfAAAAA", "A") = False
```

Two seemingly inefficient ways would be to: first convert the string to a list and check each element, or second to use a regular expression. Are there more efficient ways or are these the best one can do in Python?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised no one yet asked the following question: **what is the structure of the "non-uniform" strings that you input?** If there is one (i.e. they are not completely random), you can use the knowledge about that to optimize your algorithm.

Comment: Is efficiency of this really that important? I wonder what kind of application would have this check in the bottleneck code.

Comment: To my mind, the efficiency of that rarely can be important, though who knows? Anyway, the task is nice, and understanding what's happening inside the code and why some solutions are slow, and some are fast, is a useful training for a Python developer.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

This is by far the fastest, several times faster than even `count()`, just time it with that excellent [mgilson's timing suite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14320949/866022):

```
s == len(s) * s[0]
```

Here all the checking is done inside the Python C code which just:

- allocates len(s) characters;
- fills the space with the first character;
- compares two strings.

The longer the string is, the greater is time bonus. However, as mgilson writes, it creates a copy of the string, so if your string length is many millions of symbols, it may become a problem.

As we can see from timing results, generally the fastest ways to solve the task do not execute any Python code for each symbol. However, the `set()` solution also does all the job inside C code of the Python library, but it is still slow, probably because of operating string through Python object interface.

**UPD:** Concerning the empty string case. What to do with it strongly depends on the task. If the task is "check if all the symbols in a string are the same", `s == len(s) * s[0]` is a valid answer (no symbols mean an error, and exception is ok). If the task is "check if there is exactly one unique symbol", empty string should give us False, and the answer is `s and s == len(s) * s[0]`, or `bool(s) and s == len(s) * s[0]` if you prefer receiving boolean values. Finally, if we understand the task as "check if there are no different symbols", the result for empty string is True, and the answer is `not s or s == len(s) * s[0]`.

Comment: It probably beats count in the non-equal case because it can short-circuit the string comparison.  It still surprises me that it wins so well though.  It seems like `count` should be a simple loop which would do approximately the same amount of work that the filling of the space would do.  I suppose that filling is probably done via some impressive vectorized/optimized code in the C string library. (As is the comparison which can be short circuited).

Comment: I think that count() looks for a string, not for a single character. Probably its algorithm is much more complex than simple strncmp() in comparison of two strings. If there were a special case of count() searching for a single character, it would work much faster, but apparently there is no such case.

Comment: Ahh, right.  That must be the case.  I had forgotten that `count` could operate on strings with longer length than 1 :).  Silly me.

Comment: What if s is the empty string?

Comment: Is == taking advantage of machine-level "word" comparisons for fast string compares? So on a 64-bit system matching 4 or 8 characters at a time. To beat the memory problem, you could iterate and match against a fixed string s[0]*1024 over and over until the end. lol nice answer!

Comment: lol strmul, and to some degree count, hold up as the string scales. Here are the times I get for a source string of 1024 characters: [('test_strmul', 0.9134591826614835),
 ('test_set', 45.61518321462644),
 ('test_count', 2.706394388113573)]

Comment: @Hammerite -- empty string requires checking, here we were just testing the ideas. In addition, I don't know what to say about empty strings, True or False (is the question "check if a string contains EXACTLY ONE unique cheracter", or "check if there is not more than one unique character"). Depending on that the full answer is either "not s or s[0] * len(s) == s" or "s and s[0] * len(s) == s"

Comment: As a mathematician, my instinct is that the function should return True if s is the empty string. But the OP should really indicate.

Comment: You say 'If the task is "check if all the symbols in a string are the same"... [then throwing an exception is fine]'. I disagree. All symbols in the empty string are the same, in the sense that you cannot show me two different symbols that are in the empty string.

Comment: "All symbols in the empty string are the same"? I'd rather say that none of them are different. What is the main point: existence of equal ones, or absence of not equal? :-) So this is like a question "are points a special case of an infinitely short line?" Purely depends on initial set of definitions. So I find all the three options possible.

Comment: Surely it should be ``s == len(s) * c[0]`` as it seems to me ``s == len(s) * s[0]`` just tests that a string is made up of the same character. Whereas the original OP was implying that there were 2 variables s(tring) to test against and (c)character to check for.

Comment: "no symbols mean an error, and exception is ok" -- according to who exactly?

Comment: According to common Python conventions. Errors should raise exceptions. However, the key word is "if". If the task is "check if all the symbols in a string are the same", that at least assumes the symbols to exist. But the other versions of the task text do not. So, it's correct just to ask "What would you like to get in empty string case?" Everything is possible. :-)

Comment: Means the asterisk "repetition of spaces" or rep. of chars here? The comparison is too short to understand "at heart" for me.

Comment: It's repetition of the string. The string to be repeated is s[0] and consists of a single symbol.

Answer (score 49):

```
>>> s = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
>>> s.count(s[0]) == len(s)
True
```

This doesn't short circuit.  A version which does short-circuit would be:

```
>>> all(x == s[0] for x in s)
True
```

However, I have a feeling that due the the optimized C implementation, the non-short circuiting version will probably perform better on some strings (depending on size, etc)

---

Here's a simple `timeit` script to test some of the other options posted:

```
import timeit
import re

def test_regex(s,regex=re.compile(r'^(.)\1*$')):
    return bool(regex.match(s))

def test_all(s):
    return all(x == s[0] for x in s)

def test_count(s):
    return s.count(s[0]) == len(s)

def test_set(s):
    return len(set(s)) == 1

def test_replace(s):
    return not s.replace(s[0],'')

def test_translate(s):
    return not s.translate(None,s[0])

def test_strmul(s):
    return s == s[0]*len(s)

tests = ('test_all','test_count','test_set','test_replace','test_translate','test_strmul','test_regex')

print "WITH ALL EQUAL"
for test in tests:
    print test, timeit.timeit('%s(s)'%test,'from __main__ import %s; s="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"'%test)
    if globals()[test]("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") != True:
        print globals()[test]("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        raise AssertionError

print
print "WITH FIRST NON-EQUAL"
for test in tests:
    print test, timeit.timeit('%s(s)'%test,'from __main__ import %s; s="FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"'%test)
    if globals()[test]("FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") != False:
        print globals()[test]("FAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        raise AssertionError
```

On my machine (OS-X 10.5.8, core2duo, python2.7.3) with these contrived (short) strings, `str.count` smokes `set` and `all`, and beats `str.replace` by a little, but is edged out by `str.translate` and `strmul` is currently in the lead by a good margin:

```
WITH ALL EQUAL
test_all 5.83863711357
test_count 0.947771072388
test_set 2.01028490067
test_replace 1.24682998657
test_translate 0.941282987595
test_strmul 0.629556179047
test_regex 2.52913498878

WITH FIRST NON-EQUAL
test_all 2.41147494316
test_count 0.942595005035
test_set 2.00480484962
test_replace 0.960338115692
test_translate 0.924381017685
test_strmul 0.622269153595
test_regex 1.36632800102
```

The timings could be slightly (or even significantly?) different between different systems and with different strings, so that would be worth looking into with an actual string you're planning on passing.

Eventually, if you hit the best case for `all` enough, and your strings are long enough, you might want to consider that one. It's a better algorithm ... I would avoid the `set` solution though as I don't see any case where it could possibly beat out the `count` solution.

If memory could be an issue, you'll need to avoid `str.translate`, `str.replace` and `strmul` as those create a second string, but this isn't usually a concern these days.

Comment: WOW! It seems I have found a faster version:

s == len(s) * s[0]

Comment: @oefe -- You never really know anything until you actually measure :)

Comment: How does the RE `^(.)\1*$` compare?

Comment: @Barmar -- I don't know?  Sorry, I'm not a regex guru, so you might need to spell this one out for me so I can add it to the test-suite.

Comment: And I'm not a regular Python programmer. But something like `re.match('^(1)\1*$', s)`.

Comment: @Barmar -- Your regex solution is in the middle somewhere.  Not bad.

Comment: '^' in regex is not required for match(), and removing '^' makes the regex solution a little faster.

Answer (score 17):

You could convert to a set and check there is only one member:

```
len(set("AAAAAAAA"))
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using the built-in function [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
all(c == 'A' for c in s)
```

Comment: @InbarRose -- Those time differences are on the order of 1% -- It's not worth worrying about IMHO.  Especially considering that `is` is relying on a `Cpython` implementation detail.

Comment: @mgilson I do not remember exactly where I read it, but I recall that when dealing with char comparison its better to use `is`.

Comment: @InbarRose -- I doubt it.  AFAIK, there is no guarantee that characters are singletons (though I suppose I could be wrong about this)

Comment: I don't think `is` is guaranteed to work.  It's relying on an implementation detail of the interpreter, namely interning of strings, which isn't guaranteed according to the Python spec as far as I recall.  Yes it will probably work everywhere at least for short strings, but 'probably' is not really the best thing to rely on.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to check if all the characters in the string are same and is equal to a given character, you need to remove all duplicates and check if the final result equals the single character.

```
>>> set("AAAAA") == set("A")
True
```

In case you desire to find if there is any duplicate, just check the length

```
>>> len(set("AAAAA")) == 1
True
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding another solution to this problem

```
>>> not "AAAAAA".translate(None,"A")
True
```

Comment: Surprisingly, `translate` is winning in my timings ... (but not by much) (+1).

Comment: And apparently not winning for too long.  You've been beat out by `s == s[0]*len(s)` :)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting answers so far. Here's another:

```
flag = True
for c in 'AAAAAAAfAAAA':
    if not c == 'A': 
        flag = False
        break
```

The only advantage I can think of to mine is that it doesn't need to traverse the entire string if it finds an inconsistent character.

Comment: that's what `all` does as well. once it finds a value which is false, it stops.

Comment: Interesting. Makes sense. Still, probably more efficient than the set method, right?

Comment: you can check yourself with [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
not len("AAAAAAAAA".replace('A', ''))
```

Comment: not len("AAAAAAAAA".replace('A', ''))


#0 means True, so not operator is required

Comment: Made an addition to your timing suite. My version is still much worse than count() if the string consists of "A"s, but slightly better when the first char is 'f'.