# How do I print words with only 1 vowel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code so far, but since i'm so lost it doesn't do anything close to what I want it to do:

```
vowels = 'a','e','i','o','u','y'
#Consider 'y' as a vowel

input = input("Enter a sentence: ")

words = input.split()
if vowels == words[0]:
    print(words)
```

so for an input like this:

```
"this is a really weird test"
```

I want it to only print:

```
this, is, a, test
```

because they only contains 1 vowel.

Comment: Expected output for `""thiis iis a"`?

Comment: `input = input(...)` bad idea - you're rebinding the builtin input so next time you try to use it, it will fail

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
vowels = set(('a','e','i','o','u','y'))

def count_vowels(word):
    return sum(letter in vowels for letter in word)

my_string = "this is a really weird test"

def get_words(my_string):
    for word in my_string.split():
        if count_vowels(word) == 1:
            print word
```

Result:

```
>>> get_words(my_string)
this
is
a
test
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is easier to read, but maybe `sum(1 for letter in word if letter in vowels)` would also work.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option:

```
import re

words = 'This sentence contains a bunch of cool words'

for word in words.split():
    if len(re.findall('[aeiouy]', word)) == 1:
        print word
```

Output:

```
This
a
bunch
of
words
```

Comment: `[w for w in words.split() if re.match('[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy]*$', w)`. regex is slow for this though

Comment: I suggest to compile the regular expression (both in Kenosis and gnibbler). The pattern is fixed, and the regular expression is likely to be reused many times. Compiled regular expresions are pretty fast.

Answer (score 4):

You can translate all the vowels to a single vowel and count that vowel:

```
import string
trans = string.maketrans('aeiouy','aaaaaa')
strs = 'this is a really weird test'
print [word for word in strs.split() if word.translate(trans).count('a') == 1]
```

Comment: How about a short circuiting version that stops if `count('a')` gets to `2`?

Comment: @gnibbler -- In most *usual* cases, I've found that a simple `count` out-performs the short-circuiting version simply due to the overhead associated with the generator (and the efficiency of `str.count`).  e.g. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14320949/748858)

Comment: Yeah it was tongue in cheek. Your version is faster than mine (at least for the given string) by the way. I expect it's because `str.translate` is faster when doing translations than deletions.

Comment: @gnibbler -- maybe.  You also have 2 global lookups with `len` for each word whereas I don't have any.  For smallish strings, that might be a performance consideration ...

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = "this is a really weird test"
>>> [w for w in s.split() if len(w) - len(w.translate(None, "aeiouy")) == 1]
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

Not sure if words with no vowels are required. If so, just replace `== 1` with `< 2`

Comment: Clever way to avoid the `string` import that I needed and also only iterating over the substring once (where mine does it twice).  I'm not sure if I would rather read this version or my version, but ... +1

Answer (score 0):

You may use one for-loop to save the sub-strings into the string array if you have checked he next character is a space.
Them for each substring, check if there is only one a,e,i,o,u (vowels) , if yes, add into the another array

aFTER THAT, FROM another array, concat all the strings with spaces and comma

Comment: This question is tagged with python, strings arrays?

Comment: you need to refer this, it really exists
http://jpython.blogspot.hk/2010/08/string-array.html

Comment: You mean , words=[] is  a list ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u','y')
words = [i for i in input('Enter a sentence ').split() if i != '']
interesting = [word for word in words if sum(1 for char in word if char in vowel) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

i found so much nice code here ,and i want to show my ugly one:

```
v = 'aoeuiy'
o = 'oooooo'

sentence = 'i found so much nice code here'

words = sentence.split()

trans = str.maketrans(v,o)

for word in words:
    if not word.translate(trans).count('o') >1:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*I find your lack of regex disturbing.*</sup>

Here's a plain regex only solution [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/t6yL6a):

```
import re

str = "this is a really weird test"

words = re.findall(r"\b[^aeiouy\W]*[aeiouy][^aeiouy\W]*\b", str)

print(words)
```