# Validate a two characters code using python

Tags: python, regex

I want to verify that a string is a valid code; in particular, it should be a pair of two characters. Think of a 2-chars country code. Using the `re` module I came up with the following:

```lang
valid = re.compile('([a-zA-Z]){2,2}')
if valid.match(s) and len(s) == 2:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I feel this is not at all optimal. How can I optimize this test?

Comment: Well, you can anchor the regular expression with `^`...`$` and then you won't need the `len` check.  You can also use `{2}` instead of `{2,2}`, and you don't need parentheses around the character class.  But what is the exact requirement for the format of the string?  Two letters?

Comment: Your regex should be, `r'^[a-zA-Z]{2}$'`

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your regex, @AvinashRaj.

Comment: `return s == 2 * s[0]`

Adapted from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320909/efficiently-checking-that-string-consists-of-one-character-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just return the result of a simple test for `str.isalpha()` plus a length test:

```
return len(s) == 2 and s.isalpha()
```

For byte strings in the default `C` locale (e.g. you didn't change the locale with the `locale` module) that'll only be true for strings containing two ASCII letters (uppercase or lowercase).

If you must use a regular expression, then anchor the expression:

```
return re.match('^[a-zA-Z]{2}$', s) is not None
```

The `is not None` test also gives you a boolean. The `^` anchor is implied by `re.match()` but making it explicit doesn't hurt.

Not using a regular expression is faster however:

```
>>> import timeit, re, random
>>> tests = [''.join([chr(random.randrange(256)) for _ in range(2)]) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> def test_str_isalpha(s):
...     return len(s) == 2 and s.isalpha()
... 
>>> def test_regex(s, pattern=re.compile('^[a-zA-Z]{2}$')):
...     return pattern.match(s) is not None
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('for s in tests: test(s)', 'from __main__ import tests, test_str_isalpha as test', number=10000)
2.140676975250244
>>> timeit.timeit('for s in tests: test(s)', 'from __main__ import tests, test_regex as test', number=10000)
3.8515820503234863
```

Comment: Great! Can you please add a link explaining the `return`'s syntax?

Comment: @Dror: what part of the expression isn't clear? All I do is use a [boolean expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in one and [comparison expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) in both.