# Filtering out sublist from list based on contents of entire sublist?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, filtering, list-comprehension

So here is what I have:

```
lst = [["111","101","000"],["1001","1100","1111"],["00","11","00"]]
```

And I want to filter out the sublists that contain only strings of "0"*len(string) and "1"*len(string). The result should look like this:

```
[["111","101","000"],["1001","1100","1111"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break up the task into smaller parts. Then combine to get the solution:

```
# check that a string is all 0 or all 1
def check_string(s):
    size = len(s)
    return s in ('0'*size, '1'*size)

# check that a list contains only strings that satisfy check_string
def check_list(l):
    return all(check_string(s) for s in l)

lst = [["111","101","000"],["1001","1100","1111"],["00","11","00"]]

result = [l for l in lst if not check_list(l)]
```

Then we have

```
>>> print(result)
[['111', '101', '000'], ['1001', '1100', '1111']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I liked your explanation and the clarity of your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it with regular expressions:

```
import re

[[y for y in x if not (re.match('1+$', y) or re.match('0+$', y))] for x in lst]
```

And here is a better clever way inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14321721/3171657):

```
[[y for y in x if not (y == len(y) * y[0])] for x in lst]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `^` and `$` when using `match` since they are implicit.

Comment: @MartinKonecny  Good point about the `^` but I think you still need the `$`. `re.match('1+')` will match any string that starts with a 1, even if it has 0's in it.

Answer (score 1):

With generator expressions:

```
lst = list([x for x in lst if not all([y == y[0]*len(y) for y in x])])
```

Note: This is better than @Tum's answer because it takes the list as a whole (e.g., `["111","101","000"]`) rather than individually accepting or rejecting each value (e.g., accepting `"101"` but rejecting `"111"` and `"000"`, leaving `["101"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the `filter` function as follows:

```
import re

orig_list = [["111","101","000"], ["1001","1100","1111"], ["01","10"]]

def checker(item):
    for idx in item:
        if re.search(r'^1*$', idx) or re.search(r'^0*$', idx):
            return True
    return False

new_list = list(filter(checker, orig_list))
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['111', '101', '000'], ['1001', '1100', '1111']]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
[lst[j] for j in set([k for k, i in enumerate(lst) for m in i if m[0]*len(m) != m])]
```

In this case think about m[0]: if you have empty string what does it mean in your case? You can exclude it also.