# How to cancel the words from a list that have same letters?

Tags: python

Say I have a list and it include words like `"aa"` and `"bb"`. How I will be able to cancel all those same letter words?

Comment: typo `CleasingTest` => `CleansingTest`

Comment: Well... `CleasingTest` isn't defined.

Comment: Also, you never called the `readWordList()` function. `for i in readWordTest` doesn't work the way you think it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, typo. `CleasingTest` is missing an `n`.

Here's what you were after anyways. `filter`-ing out those values that have all the same letter.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def not_all_letters_same(s):
    return s != s[0]*len(s)

response = urlopen("http://www.cs.queensu.ca/home/cords2/shortList.txt").read().decode('utf-8')
words = list(filter(not_all_letters_same, response.split()))
```

Output

`['abs', 'abraham', 'absent', 'abilities', 'aaron', 'ability', 'absorption', 'about', 'above', 'abc', 'aboriginal', 'abstracts', 'absence', 'aberdeen', 'abortion', 'absolutely', 'able', 'ab', 'abandoned', 'abstract', 'abroad', 'absolute']`

Comment: thx man just wanna ask what exactly does import do? And I can't really understand the return part.

Comment: You already had `import` in your original code. Regarding the return statement, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320909/efficiently-checking-that-string-consists-of-one-character-in-python

Comment: Thank u so much man. Just started and way ahead to go.