# Verifying if user input is in multiple zero values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can we check if a user enters the value `0` multiple times in a row?

I have tried below code- here I have tried to define multiple value in list, but if the user enters 000000000 or more,  I have to define till 000000000 in list is there any other way to achieve this

```
  list = [0,00,000,0000]

  num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

  if num in list:

       print("Zero")

  elif :  
       print(" None ")
```

Comment: soo the number can only have 0's?

Comment: yes, actually have created similar in my test pgm when user enter 0 i have added required handler like if val == 0 but if he enter multiple 0's then this handler doesn't work

Comment: what about `if num == 0`? I tested with multiple 0 values and it still works. also dont use built-in function name `list` as variable name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320909/efficiently-checking-that-string-consists-of-one-character-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the input as a string. And you can check if the user has entered a string that will have all zeros in it as follows

```py
def all_zeros(string):
    return all(ch == '0' for ch in string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
num = input("Enter: ")

if num.count('0') > 0  and num.startswith('0'):
    print("0")
else:
    print("none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked in this way

> How can we check if a user enters the value 0 multiple times in a row?

But, other answers were checking whether more than one `0`'s are present in the string or not. I assume you want to check continuous zero's only,

```
num = input("Enter Number: ") # returns string

if "00" in num: #checking substring 
    print("Found continuous zeros")
else:
    print("Entered no continous zeros!")

value = int(num) # convert it to int if needed
```

It doesn't matter how many zeros in the string, all these `[00,000,0000,00000...]` belong to the same category.

**Output:**

```
>>> num = input("Enter Number: ")
Enter Number: 0008
>>> num
'0008'
>>> "00" in num
True
>>>
```

Comment: thnks any way to handle input like 0008 , current Found continuous zeros any way to make it read as 8 only in such cases

Comment: No, it won't read ```0008``` as ```8```, since ```input()``` take user input values as string only. (updated answer for reference)

Answer (score -1):

```
num = input("Enter: ")
if num.count("0") > 1 and int(num) == 0:
    print("0")
else:
    print("none")
```

don't change num to int it will remove all the trailing zeroes

Comment: The OP wants to detect a string containing _only_ zeroes, this code detects that a string contains more than one zero